# soapUI assertion where value is groovy reserved word

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a response that contains the following:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <project:loginResponse xmlns:project="http://project.somewhere.com/">
         <return>34715527grsbN3C</return>
      </project:loginResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I need to get the value in  for a session ID but I get error probably because return is a reserved word.  I have tried to escape it but that just treats the line as comments.

```
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("login - Request 1#Response" )
return = holder.getNodeValue( "//return" )
assert return != null
assert return.length() > 0
returnNode = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(loginResponse)
sessID = returnNode.getNodeValue("//return")
log.info(sessID)
assert sessID !=null
context["sessID"] = sessID
```

Comment: what is the error you get?  On what line?

Answer (score 2):

WHat happens if you use variable names that are not reserved words?

```
ret = holder.getNodeValue( "//return" )
assert ret != null
assert ret.length() > 0
```